# How did the Dominican Civil War impact culture?

Tags: political-history, cultural-history, latin-america

I'm trying to find information about any cultural changes caused by the Dominican Civil War-- whether that be more or less radical politics, a general move to the right or left, hostility towards foreign interventionism that wasn't present before, any change in views on women in the workforce, tradition, etc. However, I'm having trouble finding information on this.

I've looked through the first 3 or so pages of google scholar, my school library, and some of jstor, -- I'm not fluent in Spanish though, so it's harder for me to determine what sources are worth reading through all of, but I'd ideally like to find Spanish sources. I found some information here, [¿Cuándo cambió el dominicano de hoy?](https://www.diariolibre.com/opinion/en-directo/cuando-cambio-el-dominicano-de-hoy-FD22211150), but I'd prefer more scholarly sources and specific to culture ideally.

Any sources in English or Spanish would be wonderful!! Thank you!

Comment: Good question. For those wondering, the [WP page on this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominican_Civil_War) doesn't have any words on the aftermath or impact. Seems quite likely it had *some* impact, at least locally.

Comment: I also skimmed through sections a book written at the time-- "En el barrio no hay banderas" to try to see if I could draw any conclusions about how the war impacted culture; I found that the US insistence on imposing their government structure and increasing capitalism likely lead to some ppl feeling out of place w increasing tech, etc., but my literary overanalysis of a book with my minimal Spanish skills is hardly a scholarly reference unfortunately.